# json parsing in objective c

Tags: iphone, json

while parsing the content of a .json file, string like "`jamie's`" is represented as "`jamie &#039;s`".Any one know why it is so?

Comment: Any chance you could post that section of the JSON and the name of the parser you are using?

Comment: Which library you use to encode your json?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using application/json as a content type to transfer the data from the server to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go through following link
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-json-twitter-api/

Answer (score 0):

because the apostrophe is a special charachter and cant be transmitted inside of http packets. all special characters must be replaced with escape sequences like `&#039;` or with percent escapes %27 ...

in the `NSString` class you will find the methods '`stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`' and '`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`' for handle percent escapes.

the escape sequencies you must handle by yourself for example with '`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@#039;" withString:@"'"`' ...